# how to display data in jqgrid using a post ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I cant seem to find a way to display the data using post ajax

When i predefined the json data inside a variable it does read. But when i retrieve the data from the server using post ajax and display it in jqgrid it doesnt seem to work.

Heres my code:

```
  var grid_selector = "#grid-table";
    var pager_selector = "#grid-pager";

    $.post(pathFile+"loadPaymentDetails",{id:id,action:'loadPaymentDetails'},function(response,status){
        var result = [{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"82","payment_id":"82","2":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","payment_issue_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","3":"100","payment_ref_number":"100","4":"0","payment_mode_id":"0","5":"121212","payment_amount":"121212","6":"","payment_description":""}];
        if (status == "success") {

        var grid_data =  response
        $(grid_selector).jqGrid({
                data: grid_data,
                datatype: "local",
                height: 250,
                colNames:[' ', 'payment_issue_date','payment_ref_number'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'myac',index:'', width:80, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false

                    },
                    {name:'payment_issue_date',index:'payment_issue_date', width:60, sorttype:"int", editable: true},
                    {name:'payment_ref_number',index:'payment_ref_number',width:90, editable:true, sorttype:"date"},

                ], 

                viewrecords : true,
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                pager : pager_selector,
                altRows: true,
                //toppager: true,

                multiselect: true,
                //multikey: "ctrlKey",
                multiboxonly: true,



                //editurl: $path_base+"/dummy.html",//nothing is saved
                caption: "jqGrid with inline editing",


                autowidth: true

            });
        }
    })
```

I can display the data in jqgrid using the result variable but when i use the response from the ajax call it doesnt seem to work although there output is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

`$("#tab_vsebine").jqGrid({ 
        mtype: 'POST',
        url:<your ajax url call>, 
        postData: {param1:value, param2:value,...},
        datatype: "json", 
        colNames:[...], 
        colModel:[...],
        .
        .
        .
    });`